# HTML elements in utf8 in a php file?

Tags: php, html, utf-8

I'm having problems displaying unicode characters in a php file.

The thing is that the line `<td>Märkus</td>` and `<td>Tooterühm</td>` don't display the "ä" and "ü" characters.
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Here's the entire code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Sisestamine</title>

</head>

<body>

<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');


session_start();

    echo 'Tere tulemast, '.$_SESSION['user']. '<br> <br>';




if(isset($_POST['save'])){


include 'config.php';



extract($_REQUEST);

$user = $_SESSION['user']; 


$query=mysql_query("insert into norse5_proov SET osakond='$osakond', soetusaasta='$soetusaasta', it_number='$it_number', tooteruhm='$tooteruhm', mudeli_nimetus='$mudeli_nimetus', sn='$sn', riigivara_nr='$riigivara_nr', inventaari_nr='$inventaari_nr', maja='$maja', ruum='$ruum', vastutaja='$vastutaja', markus='$markus', kasutajanimi='$user'") or die(mysql_error());


if($query){


echo "Andmed sisestatud";


}

}

?>


<form action='#' method='post' border='0'>

<table>
<br>
<tr>

<td>Osakond</td>

<td><input type='text' name='osakond' /></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>Soetusaasta</td>

<td><input type='text' name='soetusaasta' /></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>IT Number</td>

<td><input type='text' name='it_number' /></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>Tooterühm</td>

<td><input type='text' name='tooteruhm' /></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>Mudeli nimetus</td>

<td><input type='text' name='mudeli_nimetus' /></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>SN</td>

<td><input type='text' name='sn' /></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>Riigivara nr</td>

<td><input type='text' name='riigivara_nr' /></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>Inventaari nr</td>

<td><input type='text' name='inventaari_nr' /></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>Maja</td>

<td><input type='text' name='maja' /></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>Ruum</td>

<td><input type='text' name='ruum' /></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>Vastutaja</td>

<td><input type='text' name='vastutaja' /></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>Märkus</td>

<td><input type='text' name='markus' /></td>


<tr>

<td></td>

<td>

<input type='submit' value='Salvesta' name="save" />
<br>
<br>

<a href="update.php">Uuenda andmeid</a><br>
<a href="delete.php">Kustuta andmeid</a><br>
<a href="show_data.php">Kuva andmeid</a><br>
<br>
<a href="index.php">Algusesse...</a>


</td>

</tr>

</table>

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

The thing is that the line Märkus and Tooterühm don't display the "ä" and "ü" characters.
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Do the chars appear and yes what does appear?

Comment: maybe they are not utf-8 encoded inputed

Comment: If you're not using `ob_*`, move your `header()` and `session_start()` BEFORE any output text (e.g. the top of your document).

Comment: ������� - This appears for the unicode characters.

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> try this......

Comment: Sometimes this problem occurs when you fetch the utf8 data from database incorrectly. Then, be sure to query 'SET NAMES utf8' before the fetch.

Answer (score 2):

Might be because you set your headers after you output content. You need to call `header` before there is any output from your script, and you should also start your session before you send your headers. The start of the file should look like this...

```
<?php 
session_start();
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

...
```

Comment: Crikey, struth! Whatcha gonna do?

Comment: The sad thing is that I have very little PHP knowledge. Should I change something else in that code you pasted above or I can just replce the first part of my code with it and it should work?
thanks in advance!

Comment: You should take the `header` and `session_start` from your code, and put it in the top of the document like I have shown here. You should then also check the other things suggested on this page... make sure your header is correct, and showing on the browser, and make sure your source file is itself saved in utf-8 encoding.

Answer (score 2):

Check that the **file is saved as UTF-8**. Sometimes files are ANSI encoded, and thus even when you set your headers correctly UTF chars are not displayed.

So check both things:

1. `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`
2. Your PHP file encoding.

*Note: if the file is not encoded with UTF-8, and you change it, remember to check special characters again, as they may change when you save the file with the new format.*

Comment: @Erlend Anderson - The file encoding is done by your editor, have a look for the proper settings there. This [W3C checker](http://validator.w3.org/i18n-checker/) could give you more insight about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure the HTTP server headers are correct.

In particular, the header:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

should be present.

The meta tag is ignored by browsers if the HTTP header is present.
 alternatively use HTML entities  for the special characters here is link for [html special character code.](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Check how the fields are encoded in database. Might be the problem is there.